# mysql / java executeUpdate how to return matched rows and updated rows

Tags: mysql, hibernate, sql-update

I need to perform an update on a given table with a condition C, with a java driver.

If there is no row matching the condition C, i need to insert a new entity in the table.
If the row exists, then the update is enought.

To do so, is it possible to return from an update query the two following informations :

```
-Matched rows count
-Updated rows count
```

I believe the executeUpdate only return the number of rows updated.
The problem is that it might be zero if the update query doesn't update anything, so i have no way to know if 0 means no match (and i'll need to perform an insert) or no update.

Note : A workaround could be to insert a random field (or date), that would be updated everytime, but i'd prefer a better solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of updated and matched rows are the same. Even if the row already has the values passed in the update, it will be counted as an updated row:

```
id   name
1    foo

update mytable set name = 'foo' where id = 1;

--> 1 row updated
```

Comment: You are right, mysql Workbench confused me (it makes the difference), but indeed the result is the matching row, updated or not. Do you know how it makes the difference between the 2 values (updated / matched) ?

Comment: No, I have no idea about that.